# Divide numbers in a line with sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a line :

```
CITY;+41119;-754831
```

I want to divide the two numbers by 10000 to get this line :

```
CITY;4.1119;-75.4831
```

I've tried the following sed command but it does nothing, what's wrong ?

```
sed 's/(.*;.*)([0-9]{4};.*)([0-9]{4})/\1\.\2\.\3/g'
```

Comment: As for what's wrong, I guess your `sed` probably doesn't support `{4}` repetition. Try with `\{4\}`, or just hard-code four instances of the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` is better tool for `performing floating point arithmetic`:

```
x='CITY;+41119;754831'
awk -F';' -v d=10000 '{print $1,($2/d),($3/d)}' OFS=';' <<< "$x"
CITY;4.1119;75.4831
```

Comment: I guess the `"+"` is not necessary, as it just indicates the sign of the 1st number. So if it was `-4100` the result should be `-4.1` and now it will print `+-4.1`.

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes I agree, I guess I just matched OP's expected output :P

Comment: @fedorqui is right, I've removed that as I can have some negative values

Comment: @Michael: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. (I removed extra + from output).

Comment: Its a request to do it with `sed`, but it can not solve this easy so using `awk` is a good solution, up voted. Here is a stipped down version `awk -F\; '{print $1,$2/d,$3/d}' OFS=\; d=10000 <<< "$x`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
 sed -r ':L;s=\b([0-9]+)([0-9]{4})\b=\1.\2=g;t L'
```

Example:

```
echo "CITY;+41119;754831" | sed -r ':L;s=\b([0-9]+)([0-9]{4})\b=\1.\2=g;t L'
```

Output:

```
CITY;+4.1119;75.4831
```

Comment: What if input is: `"CITY;+4119;754831"` OR if divisor is `500`?

Comment: Just check. ;-) Output: `CITY;+4119;75.4831`